# Binance - msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.'

Tags: node.js, api, hmac, binance

I've been trying to make an API request to the Binance using NodeJs [API as per this documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#user-universal-transfer) but I keep getting the following response and I don't know why.

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  code: -1022,
  msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.'
}
```

I've looked around the internet for a solution but all of the "fixes" do not seem to work.

Here is the actual function that makes the request to Binance:

[Biance API](https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api)

And here is my code that calls the function:

```
    const result = await binance.futuresTransferAsset("USDT", "1", [Enum.UMFUTURE_MAIN])
```

I've been stuck trying to debug this but haven't had any success so if anyone knows please help me out.

And here is the actual function:

```
futuresTransferAsset: async ( asset, amount, type ) => {
    let params = Object.assign( { asset, amount, type } );
    console.log(params)
    return promiseRequest( 'v1/futures/transfer', params, { base:sapi, type:'SIGNED', method:'POST' } );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Binance API documentation, `signature` is required for the endpoint which you try to access.

Hence include your signature in the request body inorder to get a valid response.
Which means that you must sign your request using the `HMAC SHA256` standard.

If the error still persists, I highly suggest you to use the official API of Binance instead of using some other random libraries.

You can get more information [here](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-trade-user_data-and-margin-endpoint-security)